# Application made in Automator not opening

Tags: automator, macos-high-sierra

I made a very simple application using Automator to "Get Specified URLs". I saved it as an application on my desktop, but whenever I click on the icon to open the application, it does not run. No dialogs or errors were returned. I am using High Sierra, which is the OS my computer was shipped with (no recent updates) What might be the reason behind this?

Comment: Is that the only action?  What are you doing with the URLs?

Comment: Yes, this is the only action. This action will open the specified URLs using Safari.

Comment: You can see what an action does and its input/output in the description - that action just gets the URLs you have specified, it doesn't do anything with them.  You will need to add another action, such as **Display Webpages**.

Comment: I see. I'll try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make the URLs open upon launching of the app, you will need to add the "Display Webpages" action to display the webpages you have chosen.